# Howto make gnumake behave as if default options in command line were passed?

Tags: makefile

I am using a makefile in which if I pass options in the command line like

```
make OPT1=opt1 OPT1=2
```

I get a different behavior than if I edit Makefile and write there

```
OPT1=opt1
OPT2=opt2
```

and then then run

```
make
```

on the command line.

The behavior I want is the one where I use the options in the command line.Right now I am using an alias but I am interested in knowing if this can be done purely with the Makefile alone.

Thanks.

Comment: You get different behavior? How is it different? Can you give us a makefile (the simplest one that shows the difference)?

Comment: I don't think I can. The makefile is quite complex...

Comment: That might be part of your problem right there. Is this by chance a legacy makefile that includes and/or rewrites other makefiles?

Comment: Beta, thanks for the help, I end up solving it (maybe not the best way but it works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I end up solving this was the following:

```
mv Makefile Makefile.aux
```

then create a now Makefile with the contents

```
OPT1=true
OPT2=false

DEFAULT_OPTS=--no-print-directory OPT1=$(OPT1) OPT2=$(OPT2)

.PHONY : $(MAKECMDGOALS)
$(MAKECMDGOALS):
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.aux $(DEFAULT_OPTS) $(MAKEFLAGS) $(MAKECMDGOALS)

.PHONY: all
all:
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.aux $(DEFAULT_OPTS) $(MAKEFLAGS) $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

The reason I use --no-print-directory is because if I use this method without this option it will print an extra message in the beggining and in the end of the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Does your make file use the `origin` command on these variables to decide whether to overwrite them?  This returns the, well, origin of a variable, e.g. "environment" or "command line", and maybe the makefile is written to do something different in these cases.